# Words that describes something of high quality?

Tags: meaning, descriptive-grammar

I have been searching for a business name and happened to come across this site and thought I would see if I could get some help. I run my own High End Auto Detailing company. Where I spend countless hours on luxurious and high end cars, boats and planes. I'm looking for something short and rolls smoothly. I love the name "Luxe Auto Spa" But this is already taken from a company in the state I live. I've thought of "Ritz Auto Spa" and a few others but was hoping I could get some better input on this. Thank you for helping!

Comment: If you haven't already checked it out, here's the thesaurus.com entry for *deluxe*: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/deluxe?s=t (I don't know how to format hotlinks on this site yet. Lol)

Comment: There is a trend, mostly in restaurants and clubs, to indicate luxury and exclusivity by using only the address of the establishment. For example: If the street address is "7 Main St," you could call it "Seven Main Auto Spa" - if the number is longer, say "420", you could call it "420 Auto Detailing".  (The terms "luxe" and "ritz" are considered somewhat gauche.)

Comment: Valhalla Vehicle Pampering & Pedicures

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that this word may be a little longer than you were hoping, but there can be no more superior statement of quality than ***superlative***.

> **Superlative**: Of the highest order, quality, or degree; surpassing or superior to all others.
>
> 'a superlative piece of skill'

def. source: [*thefreedictionary.com*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/superlative)

example source: [*oxforddictionaries.com*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/superlative)

Comment: I think I'd be more likely to avoid an establishment with 'superlative' in its name.

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm sure that that doesn't hold true for everyone.

Comment: "Superlative Auto Spa'?

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.